# How do i make the output of my function a list type and not NoneType?

Tags: python

the function i'm running is the following

```
def ambiguous_to_unambiguous(seq):
ambig = {'R': ['A', 'G'], 'V':['A', 'C', 'G'], 'W':['A', 'T'], 'S':['C', 'G'], 'Y':['C', 'T'], 'K':['G', 'T'], 'V':['A', 'C', 'G'], 'H':['A', 'C', 'T'],
        'D':['A', 'G', 'T'], 'B':['C', 'G', 'T'], 'N':['G', 'A', 'T', 'C']} #from IU pack
groups = itertools.groupby(seq, lambda char:char not in ambig)
splits = []
for b,group in groups:
    if b:
        splits.extend([[g] for g in group])
    else:
        for nuc in group:
            splits.append(ambig[nuc])
possible_seqs = [''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(*splits)]
print(possible_seqs)
```

I need the output of this ambiguous_to_unambiguous() function to be iterable. This is not possible at the moment because the output is a NoneType. This is the block of code i'd like to use the ambiguous_to_unambiguous() function in:

```
def seq_ID_and_weight(file_name):
with open (file_name) as file:
    ID_weight = {} #create an empty dictionary
    for seq in file:
        weight_min = [10000]
        weight_max = [0]
        if ambiguous_to_unambiguous(seq) != seq:
            possible_sequences = ambiguous_to_unambiguous(seq)
            for possib in possible_sequences:
                if possib.molecular_weight < weight_min: weight_min = possib.molecular_weight
                elif possib.molecular_weight > weight_max: weight_max = possib.molecular_weight
            ID_weight.append({seq.id: [weight_min, weight_max]})
        else:
            ID_weight.append({seq.id: seq.molecular_weight})
    print(ID_weight)
```

but this gives me the following error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-588e4dcc12bb> in <module>
----> 1 seq_ID_and_weight('short.fasta')

<ipython-input-18-ad41a9ecd674> in seq_ID_and_weight(file_name)
      7             if ambiguous_to_unambiguous(seq) != seq:
      8                 possible_sequences = ambiguous_to_unambiguous(seq)
----> 9                 for possib in possible_sequences:
     10                     if possib.molecular_weight < weight_min: weight_min = possib.molecular_weight
     11                     elif possib.molecular_weight > weight_max: weight_max = possib.molecular_weight

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

am i using this function i made wrong? i've tried the map() function and printing with the * operator but the typing remains the same.

Comment: `def ambiguous_to_unambiguous(seq):` has no ` return`  so it returns None. You should do something like `return possible_seqs`. Also your code isn't indented correctly so it's hard to read and wrong.

Comment: very sorry, it didn't paste correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a function has no `return` statement, it "returns" None.